# Установка linux на флешку

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

Меня интересует не сам процесс установки, а возможные проблемы и трудности.

Я хочу установить рядом со своей Windows-10 Ubuntu. Причем располагаться дистрибутив будет именно на флешке, т. к. SSD отдавать под linux с возможной потере данных не хочется.

И возникает вопрос, что будет, если по какой-то причине флешка отсоединится от ноутбука?

1 вопрос: смогу ли я после перезагрузки (без флешки) автоматически зайти в Windows? Или загрузчик будет убит?

2 вопрос: если я переподключу флешку к ноутбуку, смогу ли я зайти в linux после перезагрузки, или же мне придется переустанавливать linux, что скорее всего приведет к потере данных?

Comment: *т. к. SSD отдавать под linux с возможной потере данных не хочется.* - а почему для linux возможна потеря данных, а для windows - нет? Или вы что-то другое имели в виду?

Comment: имеется в виду то, что на единственном доступном мне ssd у меня хранятся файлы с окон, разные программы и т д и т п. В общем, я просто объяснил причину, почему установка **именно на флешку**, отсюда и вопросы, связанные с рассоединением носителя.

Comment: Будет режим Live USB или "честная установка", но будет выбран диск - USB?

Comment: Так это не является причиной НЕ установки на SSD, ведь если есть место, можно поставить на SSD одновременно и windows, и linux

Comment: @dlm0n , не суть. необходима именно флешка

Comment: @TotalPusher , не знаком с данными терминами.

Comment: @Shift, есть режим Live USB - полностью все грузится с флешки, на ОС на SSD влияния не оказывает ну вообще никак. Как раньше если застали те времена, загрузка с Live CD. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: @TotalPusher , в таком случае, Live USB. Все, связанное с Linux у меня будет только там.

Comment: @Shift это вопрос или утверждение? Live USB имеет один недостаток - так как монтируется в память, все поставленные программы и файлы существуют только до перезагрузки.

Comment: Предлагаю дальнейшее обсуждение в комментариях переместить [сюда](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110888/linux---)